# Can I plot only 3D coordinates using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

How can I plot a 3D coordinate without any points on it?
I tried to replace the z=z_data.as_matrix() with z = [] in the following code, but I didn't get anything.

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

data = [
    go.Surface(
        z=z_data.as_matrix()
    )
]
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Mt Bruno Elevation',
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    margin=dict(
        l=65,
        r=50,
        b=65,
        t=90
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.plot(fig, filename='elevations-3d-surface')
```

Comment: Did you try using `go.Scatter3d`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it shows nothing. Maybe I didn't use it correctly. Do you have a sample code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to plot 3D coordinates in Plotly, you need to provide 3 input lists/data frames/etc with the `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates.

```
data = [
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=val_x,
        y=val_y,
        z=val_z,
        mode='markers'
    )
]
```

You can use the dataset linked in the question and convert it to such a list, e.g.

```
# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

# totally inelegant approach to convert the dataframe to a dictionary to convert it to a list
z_dict = z_data.to_dict()

val_x = []
val_y = []
val_z = []

for x in z_dict:
    for y in z_dict[x]:
        val_x.append(x)
        val_y.append(y)
        val_z.append(z_dict[x][y])
```

which will give you the following plot.

[image]

**Complete code**

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

# totally inelegant approach to convert the dataframe to a dictionary to convert it to a list
z_dict = z_data.to_dict()

val_x = []
val_y = []
val_z = []

for x in z_dict:
    for y in z_dict[x]:
        val_x.append(x)
        val_y.append(y)
        val_z.append(z_dict[x][y])

data = [
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=val_x,
        y=val_y,
        z=val_z,
        mode='markers'
    )
]
fig = go.Figure(data=data)
py.plot(fig, filename='elevations-3d-surface')
```

Comment: Thanks for code. But I want is an empty coordinates. In other words, I want to remove all the points in the graph but still leave the coordinates there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. Can you add an example of the desired output to your questions?